# How to get two number within the attr and place them back to the attr

Tags: jquery, regex, attr

```
 <path id= "path1" d="m11,222.2L333,444L55,66 -77,-88" />
 <path id= "path2" d="m9,11L2,22.5L3,4 5,7"/>
```

1. I want to get the head two number within the attr "d".
   ex. 11 and 222.2 for path1
   9 and 11 for pathe2
2. and add some count to the number
   21  242.2 for path1
   19  31    for path2
3. then put the whole d back to the attr

I thought to get the d by

```
var outd=$("path").attr(d);
```

then use the Regular Expression to get the two number as they are between two alphabets
 ex.  m(number1),(number2)alphabet
Does it has any more convient way to make the point?
if don't,
then how do I catch the two numer by the Regular Expression and change attr="d"?
Thanks for your reading..

Comment: This is very hard to follow. Where does **add some count to the number 21 242.2** even come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on if you know the letters that will be there (will they always be m and L?) maybe you can use Javascript's split function?

string.split(separator, limit) - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
<script>
function splitpaths() {
    var path1 = "m11,222.2L333,444L55,66 -77,-88";

    var path1split = path1.split(",", 2);
    var path1val1 = path1split[0].replace("m", "");
    var path1val2split = path1split[1].split("L");
    var path1val2 = path1val2split[0];

    alert("Val 1: " + path1val1 + " Val 2: " + path1val2);
}
splitpaths();
</script>
```

Ok so I guess that's not very convenient, but at least it's easy to understand and it solves the string parsing problems. Next you would have to actually get the attribute from the path tag, and put the value back in the attribute.

Comment: it's not very convient, but it works well.Thanks for your help!

Comment: the begining is m or M; the latter is some other English alphabet.
Just like the letter  m,M,C,c,Z,z,L,l,S,s,Q,q,T,t,A,a,H,h,V,v...
I try the above but not work.
var path1val2split = path1split[1].split("L" || "C");
can you have any sugggetion for me? thanks very much!

Comment: Most likely would need a regular expression or one of the suggestions below

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just wrap them in a `<g />`, and apply a transform?

```
$('#path1, #path2').wrapAll('<g transform="translate(10, 20)"></g>')
```

Comment: I want to change the number and want to get the accurate number.So I cant use the transform function!Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @PinRob: From the example you gave, it looked as though you wanted to pull out the numbers, add `(10, 20)` to them, then put them back. Is this correct? Because that's a job for the `translate()` option.

Comment: The translate or transform seems much more appropriate than my string split suggestion! Not familiar with paths myself.